# PHPExcel rangeToArray get only cell values (not formulas)

Tags: phpexcel, phpexcelreader

How do a use rangeToArray in PHPExcel when the cells contains formulas? It returns me the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'E-mail!C3 -> E-mail!C3 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in C:\wamp\www\projects\PHP Excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 300
```

I did some tests and it only works when I remove the formulas and paste only the values.

Thanks

Comment: PHPExcel can handle most formula perfectly well; but without knowing what formula is contained in cell `'E-mail!C3` it's difficult to say.... although I guess it's possible that the hyphen in the worksheet name could be confuse with a minus sign

Comment: Thanks, i realized it was a formula looking to a value from another sheet. When I changed the formula to look inside the current sheet it worked.